# Strip parsed html text from html comments using AngleSharp

Tags: c#, anglesharp

I use the code below to strip specific html tags from parsed html using `AngleSharp` (as it is recommendable over using regular expressions to do such jobs (`AngleSharp` is currently maintained, `HtmlAgilityPack` not, hence I have been moving to the latter).

It works great - but now I want to remove html comments as well. Meaning whatever is found between `<!--` and `-->` tags.

How would this be achieved using `AngleSharp` ? Using QuerySelector does not seem suiting here.

```
private string ExtractContentFromHtml(string input)
{
    List<string> tagsToRemove = new List<string>
    {
        "script",
        "style",
        "img"
    };

    var config = Configuration.Default.WithJavaScript();

    HtmlParser hp = new HtmlParser(config);
    List<IElement> tags = new List<IElement>();
    List<string> nodeTypes = new List<string>();
    var hpResult = hp.Parse(input);

    try
    {
        foreach (var tagToRemove in tagsToRemove)
            tags.AddRange(hpResult.QuerySelectorAll(tagToRemove));

        foreach (var tag in tags)
            tag.Remove();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _errors.Add(string.Format("Error in cleaning html. {0}", ex.Message));
    }

    var content = hpResult.QuerySelector("body");

    return (content).InnerHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

After playing with the code above and AngleSharp's API, I came up with the following working solution.
Initially I thought I could replace all my tag-removing stuff and solely rely on treating text nodes only, but this is not recommendable,
since some text nodes will be generated on the fly via javascript code, meaning, you need to remove javascript nodes anyway. So I left the style + img removals as well.

Worth mentioning as well that the DOM classifies nodes according to types, and one is able to find comments by searching for nodes of type 8.

```
private string ExtractContentFromHtml(string input)
{
    List<string> tagsToRemove = new List<string>
    {
        "script",
        "style",
        "img"
    };

    var config = Configuration.Default.WithJavaScript();

    HtmlParser hp = new HtmlParser(config);
    List<IElement> tags = new List<IElement>();
    List<string> nodeTypes = new List<string>();
    var hpResult = hp.Parse(input);

    List<string> textNodesValues = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        foreach (var tagToRemove in tagsToRemove)
            tags.AddRange(hpResult.QuerySelectorAll(tagToRemove));

        foreach (var tag in tags)
            tag.Remove();



/*
   the following will not work, because text nodes that are not immediate children will not be considered 
   textNodesValues = hpResult.All.Where(n => n.NodeType == NodeType.Text).Select(n => n.TextContent).ToList();
*/


        var treeWalker = hpResult.CreateTreeWalker(hpResult, FilterSettings.Text);

        var textNode = treeWalker.ToNext();
        while (textNode != null)
        {
            textNodesValues.Add(textNode.TextContent);
            textNode = treeWalker.ToNext();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _errors.Add(string.Format("Error in cleaning html. {0}", ex.Message));
    }

    return string.Join(" ", textNodesValues);
}
```